# findElements(By.xpath()) finds elements only when given full path

Tags: selenium

I've a page containing the path

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div
```

of which the bottom-most div resolves to

```
<div id="tab-topTabs--Lumber">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-topTabs--Lumber-0">2x4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-topTabs--Lumber-1">4x4</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#tab-topTabs--Lumber-2">4x6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

both of these will find the right element

```
WebElement divTopTabLumber_1 = m.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div"));
WebElement divTopTabLumber_2 = m.getDriver().findElement(By.id("tab-topTabs--Lumber"));
```

Problem - calling using the full path grabs the correct three list elements under the deepest div:

```
List<WebElement> list_lumber_0 = m.getDriver().findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div[6]/div/div/ul/li"));
```

but these do not:

```
List<WebElement> list_lumber_1 = divTopTabLumber_1.findElements(By.xpath("//div//ul//li"));
List<WebElement> list_lumber_2 = divTopTabLumber_2.findElements(By.xpath("//div//ul//li"));
```

reporting 206 elements instead of the expected 3.

Any suggestions/critiques/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would believe that this id

```
tab-topTabs--Lumber
```

is unique in HTMLDOM.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `//div[@id='tab-topTabs--Lumber']` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

if it is then use the below code to locate **all 3 li nodes:**

```
List<WebElement> list_lumber_2 = divTopTabLumber_2.findElements(By.xpath(".//descendant::li"));
```

Comment: this seems to put me closer, now showing 51 down from 206, thx! will follow this up...

Comment: it all depends on this `tab-topTabs--Lumber`, how many entry for this id?

Comment: This solution worked for the (turns-out-overly-simplified) example I posted here on SO hence the check. The real HTML is more convoluted. Thx tho, I'm sure this nugget of wisdom will help me out somewhere down the road